# OS X 10.9.2 fail to login - WindowServer crash

Tags: macos, authentication

after a recent crash I cannot seem to login with my main user anymore. TO see whats happening i created a new admin and copied the System log...Anybody able to help with this ? didn't install anything new...I am suspecting the wacom driver to cause issues because it appears pretty early in the log:

```
Apr  8 11:30:08 Joachims-MacBook-Pro.local SecurityAgent[398]: User info context values set for JoachimSA
Apr  8 11:30:08 Joachims-MacBook-Pro.local SecurityAgent[398]: Login Window login proceeding
Apr  8 11:30:09 Joachims-MacBook-Pro.local loginwindow[392]: Login Window - Returned from Security Agent
Apr  8 11:30:09 Joachims-MacBook-Pro.local parentalcontrolsd[419]: StartObservingFSEvents [849:] -- *** StartObservingFSEvents started event stream
Apr  8 11:30:09 Joachims-MacBook-Pro.local loginwindow[392]: USER_PROCESS: 392 console
Apr  8 11:30:09 Joachims-MacBook-Pro com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[175]: Background: Aqua: Registering new GUI session.
Apr  8 11:30:09 Joachims-MacBook-Pro com.apple.launchd[1] (com.wacom.WacomTouchDriver.43856[408]): Exited with code: 255
Apr  8 11:30:09 Joachims-MacBook-Pro com.apple.launchd[1]: System: Could not find requested session: Aqua
Apr  8 11:30:09 Joachims-MacBook-Pro com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[175] (com.spotify.webhelper): Unknown key: SpotifyPath
Apr  8 11:30:09 Joachims-MacBook-Pro com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[175] (com.apple.EscrowSecurityAlert): Unknown key: seatbelt-profiles
Apr  8 11:30:09 Joachims-MacBook-Pro com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[175] (com.apple.ReportCrash): Falling back to default Mach exception handler. Could not find: com.apple.ReportCrash.Self
Apr  8 11:30:09 Joachims-MacBook-Pro.local launchctl[421]: com.apple.pluginkit.pkd: Already loaded
Apr  8 11:30:09 Joachims-MacBook-Pro.local launchctl[421]: com.apple.sbd: Already loaded
Apr  8 11:30:09 Joachims-MacBook-Pro.local TabletDriver[405]: com.wacom.WacomTouchDriver.43856: Invalid argument
Apr  8 11:30:09 Joachims-MacBook-Pro.local mdmclient[425]: Starting pre-login check
Apr  8 11:30:09 Joachims-MacBook-Pro.local mdmclient[425]: Completed pre-login check.  Time: 0.1375 seconds
Apr  8 11:30:09 Joachims-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[393]: **DMPROXY** (2) Found `/System/Library/CoreServices/DMProxy'.
Apr  8 11:30:10 Joachims-MacBook-Pro.local ReportCrash[432]: Metadata.framework [Error]: couldn't get the client port
Apr  8 11:30:10 Joachims-MacBook-Pro.local ReportCrash[432]: DebugSymbols was unable to start a spotlight query: spotlight is not responding or disabled.
Apr  8 11:30:10 Joachims-MacBook-Pro.local WacomTabletDriver[405]: HIToolbox: received notification of WindowServer event port death.
Apr  8 11:30:10 Joachims-MacBook-Pro.local WacomTouchDriver[424]: HIToolbox: received notification of WindowServer event port death.
Apr  8 11:30:10 Joachims-MacBook-Pro.local WacomTouchDriver[424]: port matched the WindowServer port created in BindCGSToRunLoop
Apr  8 11:30:10 Joachims-MacBook-Pro.local WacomTabletDriver[405]: port matched the WindowServer port created in BindCGSToRunLoop
Apr  8 11:30:10 Joachims-MacBook-Pro.local TabletDriver[405]: Finish launching /Library/Application Support/Tablet/WacomTabletDriver.app/Contents/Resources/WacomTouchDriver.app
Apr  8 11:30:10 Joachims-MacBook-Pro.local WacomTabletDriver[405]: CGError CGSGetDisplaySystemState(uint64_t, CGSDisplaySystemState **): MIG error 0x10000003: (ipc/send) invalid destination port
Apr  8 11:30:10 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Apr  8 11:30:10 Joachims-MacBook-Pro com.apple.launchd[1] (com.wacom.wacomtablet[405]): Exited with code: 255
Apr  8 11:30:10 Joachims-MacBook-Pro.local loginwindow[392]: _CGSLockWindow: Cannot synchronize window backing store
Apr  8 11:30:10 Joachims-MacBook-Pro.local loginwindow[392]: CGSFlushSurfaceWithOptions
Apr  8 11:30:10 Joachims-MacBook-Pro.local loginwindow[392]: ERROR | -[PersistentAppsSupport persistentAppPreLaunch] | CGSPersistenceWillLaunchASNs returned error:268435459
Apr  8 11:30:10 Joachims-MacBook-Pro com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.WindowServer[393]): Job appears to have crashed: Abort trap: 6
Apr  8 11:30:10 Joachims-MacBook-Pro.local loginwindow[392]: _CGSLockWindow: Cannot synchronize window backing store
Apr  8 11:30:10 Joachims-MacBook-Pro.local loginwindow[392]: CGSFlushSurfaceWithOptions
Apr  8 11:30:10 Joachims-MacBook-Pro.local loginwindow[392]: CGSLookupServerRootPort: Failed to look up the port for "com.apple.windowserver.active" (1102)
Apr  8 11:30:10 Joachims-MacBook-Pro.local BezelServices 240.49[392]: __37-[DriverServices setPrefs:forDevice:]_block_invoke not applying HID prefs: no window server session dictionary
Apr  8 11:30:10 Joachims-MacBook-Pro.local loginwindow[392]: _CGSLockWindow: Cannot synchronize window backing store
Apr  8 11:30:10 Joachims-MacBook-Pro.local loginwindow[392]: CGSGetSurfaceBounds
Apr  8 11:30:10 Joachims-MacBook-Pro.local loginwindow[392]: CGSGetSurfaceBounds failed - error 268435459 (window:11, surface:813442835
Apr  8 11:30:10 Joachims-MacBook-Pro.local loginwindow[392]: CGSSetSurfaceShape failed - error 268435459 (window:11, surface:813442835, bounds:{{0, 0}, {16, 16}}
Apr  8 11:30:10 Joachims-MacBook-Pro.local loginwindow[392]: _CGSLockWindow: Cannot synchronize window backing store
Apr  8 11:30:10 Joachims-MacBook-Pro.local loginwindow[392]: CGSFlushSurfaceWithOptions
Apr  8 11:30:10 Joachims-MacBook-Pro.local loginwindow[392]: _CGSLockWindow: Cannot synchronize window backing store
Apr  8 11:30:10 Joachims-MacBook-Pro.local loginwindow[392]: CGSFlushSurfaceWithOptions
Apr  8 11:30:10 Joachims-MacBook-Pro.local WacomTouchDriver[424]: CGError CGSGetDisplaySystemState(uint64_t, CGSDisplaySystemState **): MIG error 0x10000003: (ipc/send) invalid destination port
Apr  8 11:30:10 --- last message repeated 4 times ---
Apr  8 11:30:10 Joachims-MacBook-Pro com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[175] (com.wacom.WacomTouchDriver.43856[424]): Exited with code: 255
Apr  8 11:30:10 Joachims-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[434]: Server is starting up
Apr  8 11:30:10 Joachims-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[434]: Session 256 retained (2 references)
Apr  8 11:30:10 Joachims-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[434]: Session 256 released (1 references)
Apr  8 11:30:10 Joachims-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[434]: Session 256 retained (2 references)
Apr  8 11:30:10 Joachims-MacBook-Pro.local parentalcontrolsd[419]: CGSLookupServerRootPort: Failed to look up the port for "com.apple.windowserver.active" (1102)
Apr  8 11:30:10 Joachims-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[434]: init_page_flip: page flip mode is on
Apr  8 11:30:10 Joachims-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[434]: Found 42 modes for display 0x00000000 [33, 9]
Apr  8 11:30:10 Joachims-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[434]: Found 1 modes for display 0x00000000 [1, 0]
Apr  8 11:30:10 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Apr  8 11:30:10 Joachims-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[434]: mux_initialize: Mode is dynamic
Apr  8 11:30:10 Joachims-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[434]: Found 42 modes for display 0x00000000 [33, 9]
Apr  8 11:30:10 Joachims-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[434]: Found 1 modes for display 0x00000000 [1, 0]
Apr  8 11:30:10 Joachims-MacBook-Pro.local loginwindow[441]: Login Window Application Started
Apr  8 11:30:10 Joachims-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[434]: WSMachineUsesNewStyleMirroring: false
Apr  8 11:30:10 Joachims-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[434]: Display 0x04272ec1: GL mask 0x3; bounds (0, 0)[1680 x 1050], 42 modes available
Apr  8 11:30:10 Joachims-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[434]: Display 0x003f003e: GL mask 0x4; bounds (0, 0)[0 x 0], 1 modes available
Apr  8 11:30:10 Joachims-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[434]: WSSetWindowTransform: Singular matrix
Apr  8 11:30:10 Joachims-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[434]: Display 0x04272ec1: GL mask 0x3; bounds (0, 0)[1680 x 1050], 42 modes available
Apr  8 11:30:10 Joachims-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[434]: Display 0x003f003e: GL mask 0x4; bounds (2704, 0)[1 x 1], 1 modes available
Apr  8 11:30:10 Joachims-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[434]: CGXPerformInitialDisplayConfiguration
Apr  8 11:30:10 Joachims-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[434]:   Display 0x04272ec1: Unit 1; Alias(1, 0x3); Vendor 0x610 Model 0x9cbb S/N 0 Dimensions 13.03 x 8.15; online enabled built-in, Bounds (0,0)[1680 x 1050], Rotation 0, Resolution 1
Apr  8 11:30:10 Joachims-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[434]:   Display 0x003f003e: Unit 2; Vendor 0xffffffff Model 0xffffffff S/N -1 Dimensions 0.00 x 0.00; offline enabled, Bounds (2704,0)[1 x 1], Rotation 0, Resolution 1
Apr  8 11:30:10 Joachims-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[434]: CGXMuxBoot: Boot normal
Apr  8 11:30:10 Joachims-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[434]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01024300, GL mask 0x00000001, accelerator 0x0000462b, unit 0, caps QEX|MIPMAP, vram 288 MB
Apr  8 11:30:10 Joachims-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[434]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01024300, GL mask 0x00000001, texture max 8192, viewport max {8192, 8192}, extensions FPRG|NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
Apr  8 11:30:10 Joachims-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[434]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01022612, GL mask 0x00000006, accelerator 0x00004293, unit 1, caps QEX|MIPMAP, vram 256 MB
Apr  8 11:30:10 Joachims-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[434]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01022612, GL mask 0x00000006, texture max 8192, viewport max {8192, 8192}, extensions FPRG|NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
Apr  8 11:30:10 Joachims-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[434]: GLCompositor enabled for tile size [256 x 256]
Apr  8 11:30:10 Joachims-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[434]: CGXGLInitMipMap: mip map mode is on
Apr  8 11:30:10 Joachims-MacBook-Pro.local ReportCrash[432]: Saved crash report for WindowServer[393] version 599.20.11 to /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/WindowServer_2014-04-08-113010_Joachims-MacBook-Pro.crash
Apr  8 11:30:10 Joachims-MacBook-Pro DMProxy[431]: assertion failed: 13C64: libxpc.dylib + 38177 [AB40CD57-F454-3FD4-B415-63B3C0D5C624]: 0x10000003
Apr  8 11:30:10 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Apr  8 11:30:10 Joachims-MacBook-Pro.local loginwindow[441]: **DMPROXY** Found `/System/Library/CoreServices/DMProxy'.
Apr  8 11:30:10 Joachims-MacBook-Pro.local xpcd[437]: loginwindow[392]: registration request failed: (0x12, 0xd) process failed sandbox check
Apr  8 11:30:10 Joachims-MacBook-Pro.local ReportCrash[432]: Removing excessive log: file:///Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/WindowServer_2014-04-08-105225_Joachims-MacBook-Pro.crash
Apr  8 11:30:11 Joachims-MacBook-Pro DMProxy[431]: assertion failed: 13C64: libxpc.dylib + 38177 [AB40CD57-F454-3FD4-B415-63B3C0D5C624]: 0x10000003
Apr  8 11:30:11 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Apr  8 11:30:11 Joachims-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[434]: Display 0x04272ec1: Unit 1; ColorProfile { 1, "Default(sRGB IEC61966-2.1)"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
Apr  8 11:30:11 Joachims-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[434]: Display 0x04272ec1: Unit 1; ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}; TransferTable (256, 12)
Apr  8 11:30:11 Joachims-MacBook-Pro.local launchctl[443]: com.apple.findmymacmessenger: Already loaded
Apr  8 11:30:11 Joachims-MacBook-Pro.local loginwindow[441]: Setting the initial value of the magsave brightness level 1
Apr  8 11:30:11 Joachims-MacBook-Pro.local loginwindow[441]: Login Window Started Security Agent
Apr  8 11:30:11 Joachims-MacBook-Pro.local com.apple.SecurityServer[14]: Session 100017 created
Apr  8 11:30:11 Joachims-MacBook-Pro.local SecurityAgent[452]: MacBuddy was run = 0
Apr  8 11:30:11 Joachims-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[434]: _CGXGLDisplayContextForDisplayDevice: acquired display context (0x7fe97b500b30) - enabling OpenGL
Apr  8 11:30:11 Joachims-MacBook-Pro com.apple.launchd[1]: System: Could not find requested session: Aqua
Apr  8 11:30:11 Joachims-MacBook-Pro.local TabletDriver[449]: com.wacom.WacomTouchDriver.43856: Invalid argument
Apr  8 11:30:12 Joachims-MacBook-Pro.local UserEventAgent[444]: Failed to copy info dictionary for bundle /System/Library/UserEventPlugins/alfUIplugin.plugin
Apr  8 11:30:12 Joachims-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[434]: **DMPROXY** (2) Found `/System/Library/CoreServices/DMProxy'.
Apr  8 11:30:12 Joachims-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[434]: Display 0x04272ec1: Unit 1; ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}; TransferTable (256, 12)
Apr  8 11:30:13 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Apr  8 11:30:13 Joachims-MacBook-Pro.local TabletDriver[449]: Finish launching /Library/Application Support/Tablet/WacomTabletDriver.app/Contents/Resources/WacomTouchDriver.app
Apr  8 11:30:13 Joachims-MacBook-Pro com.apple.launchd[1]: System: Could not find requested session: Aqua
Apr  8 11:30:13 Joachims-MacBook-Pro.local TabletDriver[449]: com.wacom.TabletDriver.44032: Invalid argument
Apr  8 11:30:14 Joachims-MacBook-Pro.local TabletDriver[449]: Finish launching /Library/Application Support/Tablet/WacomTabletDriver.app/Contents/Resources/TabletDriver.app
```

Can anybody help please ? THanks a ton :-) !!